# Regex, match only if it exists in the current string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

First of all, sorry for any spelling/grammar errors that may occur. I'm trying to get some complicated regex problem solved but I can't seem to figure out how to. I'm trying to filter out some parts of certain strings. This works, however! There is one line which is optional and that's the second one, the email. How can I tell the regex that this part is optional and should only search for if it exists in the string or not.

**Strings**

- [COMMENT] Meow[/127.0.0.1]
- [COMMENT] Shadow[/127.0.0.1]
- [COMMENT] [email] Foxy[/127.0.0.1]
- [COMMENT] [email2] PerfectAim[/127.0.0.1]

**What I've tried**

```
Regex regexUserCommented = new Regex(
    @"(\[COMMENT\])\ " +  // COMMENT
    @"(\[.*\]) " +        // Email, this needs to be optional but how?!
    @"(\w(?<!\d)[\w'-]*)" // User
);

if (regexUserCommented.IsMatch(test))
{
    var infoMatches = regexUserCommented.Split(test);
    Console.WriteLine(infoMatches[3]); // User
}
```

Anyone has any idea how I can make the email section optional? (Optional in the regex, so that if it's not in the string it doesnt do anything, that it just skips the email part, sorry for my bad English >:).

Comment: You probably want a [`?` quantifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#quantifiers) (match zero or one times). For example, `(\[.*\])?`.

Comment: Have you tried @"((\[.*\]) )?"

Comment: @rutter This seems to work atm :), but how can I exclude it from the results in `var infoMatches = regexUserCommented.Split(test);`? Sorry for all the questions >:.

Comment: @rutter Nevermind! I got it working ^-^, will post the solution later, you can also post it if you want to. (your solution works perfectly, implented it wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using groups...

```
Regex regexUserCommented = new Regex(
    @"(\[COMMENT\])\ " +  // COMMENT
    @"((\[.*\]) )?" +        // Email, this needs to be optional but how?!
    @"(\w(?<!\d)[\w'-]*)" // User
);

var match = regexUserCommented.Match(test);

if (match.Groups.Count == 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("==> {0}", match.Groups[4].Value);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("==> Not matched");
}
```

Comment: Yea, sorry for not posting the answer, had to go to work etc. I will accept your answer as it fixes the problem :).